# Forward slash (/) is not working after upgraded to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 14.04

I'm using Lenovo G580, and I have recently upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10, after this upgrade forward slash (/) is not working and long press of backspace is also not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "/" is forward slash, whereas "\" backslash. Please specify your question.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect from typing "/"? What behaviour do you get? What did "/" do before your upgrade? What program are you typing "/" to?

Comment: You can do AltGr + Q for “/”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When keyboard problems emerge after installing a new Ubuntu it may be helpful to double check the current keyboard layout and keyboard settings.

Click on the gear in the upper right of the screen

Click on *System Settings*

Click on the Keyboard Choice

Double check on the *Repeat Keys* Settings on the *Typing* tab

Click on *Text Entry* on the bottom of the *Typing* tab

See that the Input Source matches your input type (keyboard). You can also add more keyboard choices and see if any work better than the current choice. As you change the keyboard layout in this way the change is reflected in the little rectangle in the menu bar. By default you press the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> key to go switch keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Hi John's answer helped me in solving this problem. The actual problem is that in Ubuntu 14 they have set the "/" forward slash as shortcut key for the Search launcher. To solve this:

1) Click on the gear in the upper right of the screen

2) Click on *System Settings*

3) Click on the *Keyboard* Option

4) Click on the *Shortcuts* tab

5) Click on the *Search* row and hold down a new key, f.i.: "F12" or press "Backspace" to clear it.

That's it. Now you should be able to get a single forward slash again in the terminal or web browser.

Best regards,

Arjan Burggraaf

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me on ubuntu 16.04 running in virtualbox 5.2.18 under mac os.

Go to:

```
Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Keyboard layout
```

[image]
Delete all layouts except the English(UK) one.